# Is there a utility type or something similar derive the name of a key from another?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, derived-types

This is a long shot but I would like to be able to generate a new interface from an existing one but with key names that are derived for the originals.

Below is an example of the kind of thing I would like to be able to do:

Given this source object:

```
interface Car {
  brand: Brand;
  model: string;
  year: number;
}
```

I would like to be able to declare an interface:

```
interface CarSetters {
  setBrand: (brand: Brand) => any;
  setModel: (model: string) => any;
  setYear: (year: number) => any;
}
```

but I don't want to have to declare it manually like above. Rather, I would like to be able to use it like:

```
type CarSetters = Setters<Car>
```

or

```
type CarState = Car & Setters<Car>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to be a pretty simple mapping:

```
type Brand = boolean;
interface Car {
  brand: Brand;
  model: string;
  year: number;
};
type CarSetters = {
    [T in keyof Car as `set${Capitalize<T>}`]: (newValue: Car[T]) => any;
};
```

To keep symbols from causing issues, you can do:

```
type CarSetters = {
    [T in keyof Car as T extends symbol ? never : `set${Capitalize<T>}`]: (newValue: Car[T]) => any;
};
```

or

```
type CarSetters = {
    [T in keyof Car as T extends symbol ? never : `set${Capitalize<T>}`]: (newValue: Car[T]) => any;
} & {
    [T in keyof Car as T extends symbol ? T : never]: Car[T];
};
```

Comment: Wow, ok thats half the way there. Btw its actually very easy to do the capitilization: `set${Capitalize<T>}` works fine. However it doesn't work as a generic because keys can be a symbol. I've tried restricting it like: `Setter<T extends Record<string, any>>` but that doesn't really do anything.

Comment: Oh cool, Capitalize only capitalizes the first character. I was off on a tangent trying to do something along the lines of ``type upperFirst<T> = T extends `${infer C extends Character}${infer R}` ? `${Uppercase<C>}${R}` : never;``, not quite the right syntax but it's not needed anyway. Thanks

Comment: Actually this still causes an error because Capitalize needs a sting but this worked: ```type Setters<T> = {[K in keyof T as K extends string ? `set${Capitalize<K>}` : never]: (value: T[K]) => any;};```

Comment: Thank you so much. I would have never gotten it without your help. Typescript is so awesome

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work out a generic that does exactly what I want, mostly thanks to the [answer by CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71622994/1788771), which I have accepted since it does definately answer the question I asked. But I am also sharing the generics I came up with:

```
type Setters<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends string ? `set${Capitalize<K>}` : never]: (
    value: T[K]
  ) => any;
};

type State<T> = T & Setters<T>
```